# same-domain with fullcalendar and google calendar

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, fullcalendar

I am trying to show some data from my google calendar in a webpage I am developing with fullcalendar framework.

But I have the problem called same-domain origin... I don't know how to solve it. In documentation, fullcalendar says:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: 'http://www.google.com/your_feed_url/'
});
});

</script>
```

But by doing this with my public calendar just gives me problems.

I try to read calendar in json format using a php in server, but results are quite similar. No problems received about domains but events are not shown. I get an error about formatDate not being initialized so I think I am not reading events.

Any idea about how to solve this problem? I guess, if fullcalendar allows to do this with gcalendar, it means that it can be done.

I add some events in json:

```
{"version":"1.0","encoding":"UTF-8","feed":    {"xmlns":"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom","xmlns$openSearch":"http://a9.com/-    /spec/opensearchrss/1.0/","xmlns$gCal":"http://schemas.google.com/gCal/2005","id":    {"$t":"http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/aristeidhsxr%40gmail.com/public/basic"},"update    d":{"$t":"2013-08-22T09:47:26.000Z"},"category":    [{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind","term":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005    #event"}],"title":{"$t":"aristeidhsxr@gmail.com","type":"text"},"subtitle":    {"$t":"aristeidhsxr@gmail.com","type":"text"},"link":    [{"rel":"alternate","type":"text/html","href":"http://www.google.com/calendar/embed?    src=aristeidhsxr%40gmail.com"},{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/aristeidhsxr%40gmail.com/public/basic"},{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#batch","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/aristeidhsxr%40gmail.com/public/basic/batch"},{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/aristeidhsxr%40gmail.com/public/basic?alt=json&max-results=25"}],"author":[{"name":{"$t":"Î‘ÏÎ¹ÏƒÏ„ÎµÎ¯Î´Î·Ï‚ Î§ÏÎ®ÏƒÏ„Î¿Ï…"},"email":{"$t":"aristeidhsxr@gmail.com"}}],"generator":{"$t":"Google Calendar","version":"1.0","uri":"http://www.google.com/calendar"},"openSearch$totalResults":{"$t":19},"openSearch$startIndex":{"$t":1},"openSearch$itemsPerPage":{"$t":25},"gCal$timezone":{"value":"Europe/Madrid"},"gCal$timesCleaned":{"value":0},"entry":[{"id":{"$t":"http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/aristeidhsxr%40gmail.com/public/basic/2gh1aqf61krdvgr85eseoclr64"},"published":{"$t":"2013-08-22T09:47:26.000Z"},"updated":{"$t":"2013-08-22T09:47:26.000Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind","term":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event"}],"title":{"$t":"dghhfdg","type":"html"},"summary":{"$t":"CuÃ¡ndo: vie 30 de ago de 2013 21:30 al 22:30 \nCEST\u003cbr\u003e\n\n\n\u003cbr\u003eEstado del evento: bekrÃ¤ftad","type":"html"},"content":{"$t":"CuÃ¡ndo: vie 30 de ago de 2013 21:30 al 22:30Â \nCEST\u003cbr /\u003e\n\n\n\u003cbr /\u003eEstado del evento: bekrÃ¤ftad","type":"html"},"link":[{"rel":"alternate","type":"text/html","href":"http://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=MmdoMWFxZjYxa3JkdmdyODVlc2VvY2xyNjQgYXJpc3RlaWRoc3hyQG0","title":"alternate"}
```

This is part of the json file, not complete.

I tried putting a couple of events directly as one of the user said:

```
$(document).on('pageshow','#agenda',function(){    

       $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
         events: [{
                  title: 'Event 1', start: '2013-08-26T19:10:00Z', 
                  end: '2013-08-28T19:20:00Z'
                  },{
                  title: 'Event 2', start: '2013-08-27T16:25:00Z',
                  end: '2013-08-27T18:45:00Z'
                }]
      });
    });
```

But I got an error saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'formatDate' of undefined gcal.js:11
(anonymous function) gcal.js:11
(anonymous function) gcal.js:107
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure what you correct parse events from `http://www.google.com/your_feed_url/`  in php? Event start and end dates must be in `ISO 8601` format, something like this `2013-07-09T19:10:00-04:00`. You can use fullcalendar `$.fullCalendar.formatDate(from, format);` to convert date and time.

Also you can use Google [Calendar Api](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/?hl=en) to get events.

Events must looks something like this:

```
events: [{
    title: 'Event 1', start: '2013-07-09T19:10:00-04:00', 
    end: '2013-07-09T19:20:00-04:00', allDay: false
    },{
    title: 'Event 2', start: '2013-08-22T16:25:00-04:00',
        end: '2013-08-22T18:45:00-04:00', allDay: true
}]
```

For public google calendar you can do something like this:

```
var url = 'http://google.com/calendar/feeds/test@group.calendar.google.com/public/full?alt=json';
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(response){
        var googleEvents = new Array();
        for(var i = 0; i < response.feed.entry.length; i ++){
            googleEvents[i] = {
                title : response.feed.entry[i].title.$t,
                start: response.feed.entry[i].gd$when[0].startTime,
                end: response.feed.entry[i].gd$when[0].endTime
            };
        }
        //init events
        calendar = $('#calendar-container').fullCalendar({
            events: googleEvents
        });
    }
});
```

Parameter `alt` specify format for response.

Comment: I just feed with an xml file from google address or json from php file. But dates are correct formatted in both cases. The only problem is that events are not shown in second one or same-domain problem in first one

Comment: Please, paste example of your events

Comment: I added part of my json file

Comment: You set this json to fullcalendar events?

Comment: Yes, I feed events with this json file. But it doesn't load

Comment: Sorry, buts your events must be in another format. Please, see my updated code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36083/discussion-between-joni-jones-and-biribu)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your invitation. I added some info about setting events in your way. Maybe xml received from google has not the right format but trying with your events I get other error and I cannot watch them.

Comment: I try your updated events in my calendar and all works fine. http://gyazo.com/0b906abff245c5ad06e60f79a6d26d2a. Where you call ``formatDate()``? I not see in your updated code. Do you want to continue discussion in the chat?

Comment: I don't have that function in my code. I think it is used inside fullcalendar script.

Comment: Please, see my comment in chat.

Comment: This is so close but doesn't work: 'Cannot read property '0' of undefined' due to `gd$when[0]`

Comment: Try to logging ``response.feed.entry[i]`` and you will see all details of ``entry``